# Is int used in place of byte here

Tags: java

Consider we are adding 2 numbers

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
```

Why do we use int in here instead of byte? I am just revisiting the basics of the Java. 
Byte data type occupies just 1 byte whose range is from -128 to 127, inclusive.
Why do we use int here though it occupies 4 bytes and whose range is also large.
Does using `byte x = 10;` and `byte y =20;` improve the performance and save memory?
In normal programming also most often to initialize something we use int, why is it so?

**Update:**

To be more precise, here is my interpretation on this. As a byte is of size 8 bits, a certain space of 8 bits is allocated for variables x and y I guess, correct me here if I am wrong.
So, if we are declaring x and y as of type int, 32 bits of space is allocated for each variable that is x and y. Therefore, the space in our memory is occupied, though we are using small numbers like 10 and 20 for which byte data type is apt.

Please correct.

Comment: What do you do with x and y? Do they ever become larger than 127 or smaller than -128? What are they meant to represent?

Comment: We have no idea who wrote this code or its purpose... so there's no way we can reason about why the author happened to pick `int`. If you're asking "When would it be a good idea to use `int` rather than `byte`" then your example is unhelpful.

Comment: You may want to consider some JVM level implementation details also in [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23269814/1686291).

Answer (score 2):

It often makes our code *flexible*. Imagine a program where, if I typed in `128` instead of `127`, we would get inaccurate results.

I agree, that the `int` type does bring with it an unwanted overhead, but that overhead is negligible in the grand scheme of the application (for most cases).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Byte type shorts, wich are shorter than int type if you want:

```
byte x = 10;
byte y = 20;
```

It works without any problem. It could be usefull if you want to achieve memory optimisation but in 99,9% of time it's useless to use such low level optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

Usually such thing comes down to the computer architecture, not all the processors have the instructions on single bytes, natively they usually operate on int type. However the int size may differ in different architectures, using the byte on such things could come down to binary evaluation of the byte functions. The compiler can't usually tell if the values won't overflow so it can't be "smart" about optimization. Even if they won't overflow it will still need to be sure they wont. So it will binary mask the required data, move them, calculate the operation, shift them again and merge into final memory location. This is why programmers usually use the ints.

Answer (score 2):

Generally people don't use bytes for small numbers because it does not make a
difference space wise if you don't have many. Notice also that the word length
of a 32 bit computers is the same as the length of an int, so what happens with
performance is not always that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons:

1. Because if the numbers later change we do not have to think about the range / reinitliazie.
2. Because an `int` represents a number without a floating point. If we read `int` we know what it is. A `byte` represents a Byte which is something special, not a general little number. `int` is way more self explaining if you just want a number, for example for counting stuff. People will immediately recognize it and it will help understanding the code.
3. On top of that, the difference in memory usage should not matter. Its 3 byte. Even if you have 1000 variables, the difference is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

We use `int` for ordinary manipulation of the integer values and we need a common range of integers. Technically there is no problem in using `byte` as we're sure about the range of the numbers we're using, for example the following is completely a valid block of code:

```
 for (byte b = 0; b < 127; b++) {
     System.out.println(b);
 }
```

but exactly as you want to raise the upper bound to 128 it becomes an infinite loop using `byte`! So `int` in many cases is `enough` or will be enough for future changes.

BTW, using `int` in many places is really more common (for example as index of arrays) so your code will be more readable than the one using `byte` in those places.

Summary:

1. `int` contains a range of numbers that is more common in daily usages
2. Using `int` makes the program maintenance easier with a little cost
3. Using `int` in many places makes your program more readable in many cases
4. If you're writing a code that is really sensitive to the memory usage (e.g. android app) and you're sure that `byte` is enough and **will be** in the future you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you may want to consider is, **Actual type** and **Computational Type** mentioned in [JVM 2.11.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1) Specification doc. Listed in [Table 2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1-320)

Computational operations on literal type `boolean` `byte` `char` and `short` will be performed as they are type of `int`, **Thus you are not reducing any "Operational Load" on system by using `byte` instead of `int`, The instruction cycles for both will be same and will take same amount of time to operate.**

However you can definitely preserve some very very negligible amount of memory by using `byte`. but you can sacrifice that to improve readability and code structure of your program and also to minimize (-128 to 127) range risk.